# Bootstrap-tour with Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 n.popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tour

Trying to use [bootstrap-tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) with bootstrap 4 and am getting the followng error:

> TypeError: n.popover is not a function

I am initializing the code like this:

```
var tour = new Tour({
            steps: [
                {
                    element: "#nextLesson",
                    title: "Title of my step",
                    content: "Content of my step"
                }
            ]
        });
        tour.init();
        tour.start();
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the Bootstrap 4 javascript files.

Comment: Where do I find the  bootstrap 4 js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [initialize popover plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) that tour depends on:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like bootstrap-tour is not yet compatible with bootstrap 4.